# Angular 5 ng-untouched ng-dirty ng-invalid added automatically to FormGroup

Tags: javascript, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am using reactive forms and bootstrap and I am also using custom components that are nested in my root form.

The problem is, that when the input gets invalid Angular automatically adds e.g. the class ng-invalid both to the input (that is correct) and also to the form/ div that a FormGroup is attached to. (which I want to omit)

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
...
<my-custom-component [fg]="myForm"></my-custom-component>
...
</form>
```

And in my custom component I got following html.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div [formGroup]="fg">
     <input [formControlName]="myInput"/>
  </div
</div>
```

Does anyone know how/ if it is possible to not let Angular add this class to the nested components `div` where the `formGroup` is attached to?

I found following code on plunker where you can see the css classes added to the form after clicking on submit. https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/pWgeIZ